# Aurelia I18N get instance

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible to get Aurelia I18N instance in function?
Without "@inject"?

Example:

```
import {I18N} from 'aurelia-i18n';

function() {
  return I18N.getInstance().tr('word');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {I18N} from 'aurelia-i18n';


...

let i18n = Container.instance.get(I18N);
i18n.tr('word')
```